# Jira soap api: can't update any issues

Tags: php, api, soap, jira

Hi I've googled this problem for quite a bit and couldn't find the answer. Perhaps someone out here could help me.

I'm using SOAP to interact with our local installation of JIRA. I don't have any problem with getting issues, adding work logs, progressing workflow, creating issues. But when I try to edit an issue nothing happens.

Basically when I make a SOAP call to updateIssue it goes without errors but returned issues does not contain any changes I've sent. (however "updated" field which contains the timestamp of the last update will change accordingly) I thought it is a permissions problem but if I try same update call while logged in as a user without permissions to edit this issue I would get error saying that. I'm completely lost out here. I've checked log files but couldn't find anything out there either.

Does anyone have an idea why this could happen? Or how can I troubleshoot/debug it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i'm feeling stupid now. After half a day of trying to figure out why it doesn't work i finally looked into WSDL :)

And surly enough the format I was sending changes to an issue was incorrect. The correct structure for 3rd parameter in PHP looks like that:

```
$data = array('fields'=>array('id'=>'assignee','values'=>array($username)));

$this->jira->updateIssue($this->jiraAuth,$issueKey, $data);
```

The thing that throwed me off course was that in order to create an issue a simple structure like that does the trick:

```
$issue=array(
'type'=>3,
'priority'=>3,
  'project'=>'XXX',
'duedate'=>time(),
'components'=>'',
'versions'=>'',
'fixVersions'=>'',
  'assignee'=>'user1',
  'reporter'=>'user1',
'environment'=>'',
'description'=>'test',
'summary'=>'test',
'timetracking'=>'',
'attachment'=>'',
'labels'=>''

);
return $this->jira->createIssue($this->jiraAuth,$issue);
```